# Extracting LPC coefficients in Praat

Tags: praat

How can I extract a matrix of LPC coefficients and frames from a created LPC object using a Praat script? (Or, if I can figure it out using the menu buttons, I can figure out how to script it..)

I've gotten as far as using `To LPC (burg): 16, 0.010, 0.005, 50`, but I don't know how to extract the actual coefficients. I tried `Down to Matrix (lpc)` but I don't see any menu item that would let me export the coefficients themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an LPC object selected, you can Save as text file, likewise with a Matrix object created by Down.